# :first-of-type is not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, first-of-type

I have the problem, because the `:first-of-type` margin don't show. I am trying to put left and right margin to be `10px` and between elements to be `20px`.

Here is the code:

```css
#players {
  width: 960px;
  height: 283px;
  position: relative;
}

.igrac {
  width: 220px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 283px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.igrac:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.igrac:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="players">
  <div class="naslov_dela">
    <p>IGRAČI</p>
    <a href="#">Svi igrači >></a>
  </div>
  <div class="clear_fix"></div>
  <div class="igrac">
    <img src="images/players/djordjevicdusan.jpg" />
    <p>Đorđević Dušan</p>
    <p>Tehničar</p>
    <div class="boja"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="igrac">
    <img src="images/players/petrovicpetar.jpg" />
    <p>Petrović Petar</p>
    <p>Korektor</p>
    <div class="boja"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="igrac">
    <img src="images/players/jevticnemanja.jpg" />
    <p>Jevtić Nemanja</p>
    <p>Libero</p>
    <div class="boja"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="igrac">
    <img src="images/players/aleksicmilan.jpg" />
    <p>Aleksić Milan</p>
    <p>Primač</p>
    <div class="boja"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone knows why this `:first-of-type` margin does not showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't access `.igrac` using `:first/last-of-type` alone, you will need the help of sibling selectors:

- [adjacent sibling selector `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)
- [general sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```css
#players {
  /*changed to make it responsive*/
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 283px;
  position: relative;
}

.igrac {
  /* change width to fit demo view*/
  width: 125px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 283px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  /*no need for display:block - div is already a block level element*/
}

.clear_fix+.igrac,
.naslov_dela~.igrac:last-of-type {
  background: red
}

.clear_fix+.igrac {
  margin-left: 10px
}

.naslov_dela~.igrac:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
<div id="players">
  <div class="naslov_dela">
    <p>IGRAČI</p>
    <a href="#">Svi igrači >></a>
  </div>
  <div class="clear_fix"></div>
  <div class="igrac">
    <img src="images/players/djordjevicdusan.jpg" />
    <p>Đorđević Dušan</p>
    <p>Tehničar</p>
    <div class="boja"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="igrac">
    <img src="images/players/petrovicpetar.jpg" />
    <p>Petrović Petar</p>
    <p>Korektor</p>
    <div class="boja"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="igrac">
    <img src="images/players/jevticnemanja.jpg" />
    <p>Jevtić Nemanja</p>
    <p>Libero</p>
    <div class="boja"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="igrac">
    <img src="images/players/aleksicmilan.jpg" />
    <p>Aleksić Milan</p>
    <p>Primač</p>
    <div class="boja"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```